# Converging or diverging: sum of $A_n = 1/((\log{n})^{\log{n}})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I did try a lot of approaches to this question but I am yet to get a correct one that is if
$$A_n = 1/((\log{n})^{\log{n}})$$  then is the summation $\sum A_n$ convergent or divergent ?

Comment: Hint: We have $(\log n)^{\log n}=e^{(\log\log n)(\log n)}=n^{\log\log n}$.

Comment: And in particular, $1/n^{\log\log n} < 1/n^{1.01}$ for $n\ge16$.

Comment: Yeah yeah I got it

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the series converges by comparison with any series whose general term is $n^{-s}$, $s>1$.